# How to prioritise routes of multiple interfaces

Tags: arch-linux, iproute, libvirt

I have 5 ethernet interfaces (from 2 devices, 1x onboard, 4x ethernet card).

They are named....

```
eONBOARD
eA eB eC eD
```

I am using macvtap on each of the interfaces on the extra card. These are then used by libvirt guests.

I want all none guest traffic to use eONBOARD only. I don't want my host machine to use the other interfaces directly.

**ip route show**

```
default via 10.0.20.10 dev eD src 10.0.20.9 metric 202 
default via 10.0.10.10 dev eONBOARD src 10.0.10.1 metric 203 
default via 10.0.20.10 dev eC src 10.0.20.8 metric 204 
default via 10.0.20.10 dev eB src 10.0.20.7 metric 205 
default via 10.0.10.10 dev eA src 10.0.20.6 metric 206 
10.0.10.0/24 dev eONBOARD proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.200 metric 203 
10.0.10.0/24 dev eA proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.6 metric 206 
10.0.20.0/24 dev eD proto kernel scope link src 10.0.20.9 metric 202 
10.0.20.0/24 dev eC proto kernel scope link src 10.0.20.8 metric 204 
10.0.20.0/24 dev eB proto kernel scope link src 10.0.20.7 metric 205
```

As you can see, eD is the preferred route (which is causing my host problems talking to the guest on this interface).

Can anyone suggest how I can get this to work on Arch Linux?

Thanks

Comment: It's a headless server running vanilla arch. I want the route to be configured when the machine starts.